# Determine iOS sort order for ABContactsHelper

Tags: ios, contacts, abaddressbook

for an iPhone project I'm using the ABContactsHelper by Erica Sadun.
To show the contacts I wan't to use the same sort order as iOS uses in e.g. AdressBook.app.
Is there a possibility to get this information?

I tried:

```
+ (BOOL) firstNameSorting;
+ (BOOL) lastNameSorting;
```

from ABContactsHelper class but these always give me first name sorting. Even if I set lastname,firstname in contact setting.
Thanks in advance.

Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ABPersonGetSortOrdering()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABPersonGetSortOrdering) should work.

```
ABPersonSortOrdering sortOrder = ABPersonGetSortOrdering();
if (sortOrder == kABPersonSortByFirstName) {
    // sort by firstName
}
else {
    // sort by lastName
}
```

---

if you look at Ericas code you'll see that it does not return the sort order. It actually returns the display format.

from ABContactsHelper.m:

```
// Sorting
+ (BOOL) firstNameSorting
{
    return (ABPersonGetCompositeNameFormat() == kABPersonCompositeNameFormatFirstNameFirst);
}
```

that's completely wrong.

Maybe you want to skip that 4 year old, unmaintained code and write something yourself. The AddressBook framework is not that hard to understand.

Comment: That's it. Thank you. At the time I just chose it to get faster progress. Anyhow, there are existing forks github which provide iOS 5+ support...

Comment: And how do I get notified if user changes the sort order again?

Comment: @schystz you won't get notified. You have to retrieve the sort ordering as described by Matthias Bauch

Comment: @Matthias can you add please the code below for iOS 9 and higher in your answer ? thanks
`[[CNContactsUserDefaults sharedDefaults] sortOrder]`